# A book about Ruby On Rails for the Ruby illiterate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a book about Ruby On Rails for someone that has little or no understanding of Ruby?

Although Ruby On Rails is a great reason to start learning Ruby, I'd be bored out of my pants if I first have to read a full book on Ruby and then a book about Ruby On Rails.

Something that demonstrates the basic principles of both Ruby and Ruby On Rails would be an ideal intro to this world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agile Web Development with Rails (Thomas, Heinemeier Hansson) is a good intro to rails, and introduces Ruby gently along the way, you don't need to know ruby to read it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Web-Development-Rails-Programmers/dp/097669400X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/097669400X)

Comment: I bought this book from http://pragprog.com/ and have gotten free updates every time they change the book.  It's my go-to reference for the basics as well as some more advanced topics.  +1.

Comment: There is a newer edition of this book: http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition

Comment: this was my first book about both Rails and Ruby, and it was a great intro.

Answer (score 1):

AWDWR is a good place to start. A couple other books worth looking at are [Simply Rails 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980455200) and [Foundation Rails 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210397). Veger does have a good point too; without a certain level of Ruby knowledge you will struggle in some areas with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend checking out why's Poignant Guide to Ruby: http://poignant.guide/ first to get familiar with ruby, it makes it entertaining to learn. Then for Rails I would recommend Agile Web Development with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

It is wise to first learn the (basics of a) language before using more advanced frameworks in order to fully make use of the framework. Same goes for Ruby and Ruby On Rails.

Personally, I had the same problem. But I found a nice Ruby book ([Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/), explaining Ruby in a none/less boring way. I thought it was actually fun to read!

After learning the basics of Ruby you can start looking at the (somewhat) [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). They are easy to understand and shows a lot of Ruby On Rails basics (and more advanced stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Simply Rails 2 By Patrick Lenz is a good Rails introduction for someone with very little Ruby experience. But you will need another Ruby and Rails book or resource to really master both.

Answer (score 0):

A good free alternative is [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/).  It's a work in progress, but even the first 6 chapters helped me out a bunch.